# Positioning Div's

Tags: html, positioning

I am trying to position 2 Divs.

I want to have a strip spread 100% across the bottom of the page with a height of 100px and for the div to take up all of the space above it. I would like the top div to scroll and for the bottom one to have no scroll capability. Does anyone know how to code this? I am using the below code:

## menubar

{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position: absolute;
  }

## content

{
    width:100%;
    height:530px;
    position: absolute;
  }

Comment: possible duplicate of [div's height like remaining height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997573/divs-height-like-remaining-height)

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps (if using a separate CSS from your HTML):

CSS:

```
#wrapper {float: left; width: auto; heigth: auto; position: absolute; bottom: 0px;}

#top {width: 100%; Height: 100%; Position: relative; Overflow: auto;}

#bottom {width: 100%; height: 100px; position: relative; Overflow: hidden;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper"> <div id="top"> DIV CONTENT GOES HERE </div> <div id="bottom"> DIV CONTENT GOES HERE </div> </div>
```

It is recommended that you separate your CSS from the html by separate files or references. (You could also just integrate them within each other.)